# Retrieve & display selected information in different window into a form in another window using checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a form. Inside the form there are some fields for company details. User no need to fill in the field. What they are suppose to do is that they need to click on link provided and the link will pop up new window with the list of companies name in it. Beside the company name there's a checkbox. The user just need to click the checkbox to choose their company. Once done, the user will click the submit button and the selected company information will be display inside the fields in the form. My question is how can I retrieve and display the selected company information by using a checkbox and display it in the fields? Hope anyone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I guess the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151592/copy-value-in-textarea-within-two-different-forms-both-forms-in-different-asp-f) is related to this one :).

See [this](http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html).  It has an example close to what you want.